# Android NDK : C++ class with extern "C" is not building

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I am deveoping an xamarin.android sample app. I have created a C# dll, which imports ".so" library. This dll is used in android app.

I have created a c++ file and generating a ".so" library file using android NDK. 
I have included extern "C" in my C++ file. But android NDK is not building this.
If I remove the extern "C", NDK is generating ".so" file, but I am getting "No entry point found " exception in run time of application.

Anyone faced this issue..? please help me.

Comment: "not building" how? What's the error?

Comment: extern "C" i used to qualify that a function prototype or variable is linked from a C object file and is usually only used to link C code with C++ code. Can you give an example of how you are using it ?